# Stability of resonance structures

Tags: organic-chemistry

Should the fact that all atoms involved having an octet, or the rule that more electronegative element should have negative charge and less electronegative element have positive charge, be given greater priority while determining the stability of resonance structures? [image: Then what shall be the stability order of the following questions a and b?]

Comment: No formal charges if possible. The point is that when all atoms have octet and no charge separation, then that structure is a very good description for the real molecule. It will have an important weight and even more so if it happens for it to have degenerate companion, as in aromatic rings. Beside this concept, common (qualitative) rules are easily found.

Comment: Start by looking for structure with most complete octets then most number of bonds then look for if they have unlikely positive or and unlikely negative charge on the more electronegative and more electropositive atom respectively and then look for charge seperation

Comment: So what would be the answer of the above two questions?

Comment: I think I have answered.